# Extract last word of a file in bash/sed/awk

Tags: bash, file, awk, sed

I want to extract last word of a file say `a.txt` in bash/sed/awk.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To get to get the last word in the last line:

```
awk 'END {print $NF}' file
```

Answer (score 6):

Updated.

If you want to use `awk` and make sure there is a word, use this:

```
tac a.txt | awk 'NF{print $NF; exit}'
```

`tac` prints the file in reverse. `NF` in front of the `{}` block makes it work whenever the line is not empty. In such case, it prints the last field (`NF` stands for number of fields, so `$NF` is the last one), and then exits.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello my name
is blabla
and this is
my comment.
                      <--- note an empty line
$ tac a | awk 'NF{print $NF; exit}'
comment.
```

Or also, as [suggested by Kent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24159417/extract-last-word-of-a-file-in-bash-sed-awk#comment37285339_24159441):

```
awk '{w=NF?$NF:w} END{print w}' file
```

`w=$NF?$NF:w`. This is a ternary operator: if `NF>0` (no empty line), set `w` to the last field. Otherwise, keep it the way it was. Finally, in `END{}`, print the last saved word.

---

In case you want to make it with `sed`, you can use this, that works in case there is no empty lines at the end:

```
sed -n '${s/.* //; p}' a.txt
```

#### Explanation

- `$` stands for last line of the file. In that case, do what is inside `{}`.
- `s/.* //; p` remove everything up to last space. Then print `p`.

Comment: I guess he wants something like `awk 'END{print $NF}' file` I said **like** because, the last line of the file could be empty. since you came first,  you could do some fix and complete the answer.

Comment: Errr true, I did understand it wrongly. Jotne posted his answer now, so I will just remove mine.

Comment: well as I commented, `awk 'END{print $NF}' file` won't always work.

Comment: True! Just edited with a brand new solution taking this into account. Thanks, @Kent

Comment: there's no empty line in the file

Comment: +1 since OP said no empty line, it is much easier. , I just want to comment `awk '{w=$NF?$NF:w}END{print w}' file`

Comment: `s/.* //; p` is fine unless line end with a space. mya i suggest`s/.* \([[:space:]]\{1,\}[[:space:]]*$/\1/;p` so event with line with 1 word (or not, but this depend on exact resquest) on last line it works

Answer (score 1):

Try this awk command also,

```
awk -v RS="\0" '{print $NF}' file
```

`RS="\0"` turns all the records in a file to a single  single record. And then `{print $NF}` prints the last field of that single record.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use sed command ,

```
$sed -nr '${s/.* (.*)$/\1/pg}' File_name
```

Comment: you should put the `p` ouside the `s///` or it will fail if there is not at least 2 word on last line and `g` is not needed in this case, there is only 1 end per line. Finaly, it failed on line with last position is a space character.

Answer (score 1):

Using tail and grep :

```
tail -1 myFile.txt | grep -oE '[^ ]+$'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the last word with `grep` and `tail`:

```
<a.txt grep -o '\w\+' | tail -n1
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed` variant to support empty last line (if any):

```
sed -n '/[^ ]/h; ${g;s/ *$//; s/.* //p}' a.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/\w/{s/.*\W(\w+)\W*$/\1/;h};$!d;x;/./!d' file
```

Saves the last word of the current line in the hold space then deletes the line. At the end of the file it retrieves the last word and prints it out unless there was no word in which case it deletes the empty line.

An alternative way is to slurp the whole file into memory:

```
sed -r ':a;$!{N;ba};s/.*\W(\w+)\W*$/\1/p;d' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 sed -n '/^$/!{$ s/.* \(\w*\)$/\1/p}'
```

This will omit blank lines and print the last word on the last non-blank line.

- /^$/!         find non-blank lines
- $ s/          on the last line substitute
- .* (\w*)$   capture anything between the ()
- \1            substitute line for capture group ()
- p             print it